# code is not getting called as expected - jquery css selector

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Am trying to apply a style after the page gets loaded. Am writing this part of script inside my partial view.
It never gives me the controls. Always showing me length as zero.

Any clue?

```
console.log($('.pType:not(:hidden):not(:last)').length);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pType:not(:hidden):not(:last)').css("border-right", "1px solid black");
    console.log($('.pType:not(:hidden):not(:last)').length);
});
console.log($('.pType:not(:hidden):not(:last)').length);
```

**EDIT:**
if run the following code in F12 console after page gets loaded. am able to see length as 4.

$('.pType:not(:hidden):not(:last)').length)

Also those '.pType' div's am showing and hiding via ViewBag's

Comment: So no elements match the selector? Without seeing the HTML, there's not much we can do about that?

Comment: If it works in the console and not in document.ready, the elements are loaded later with ajax or something similar.

Comment: Got it!!  I just need to put a timeout. like this. '  setTimeout(function () {
            $('.pType:not(:hidden):not(:last)').css("border-right", "1px solid black");
        }, 250);'

Comment: That's not a very good solution, but you're getting the point, the elements have to be there when you check the length. Generally you'd want to hook into whatever function is loading the elements, and then run the length check when that function completes etc.

Comment: @adeneo 
So what else should i try if my solution is not recommended.???